# Storyboard Layout Change with Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5

I have just upgraded to Xcode 5 and like several others am having various issues with my Storyboard based app.

Initially when viewing the storyboard, the layouts had altered, i.e. shifted up, but I was able to simply rectify this by selecting the option to "View as 6.1 or earlier", so all was well, or so I thought. [I have one storyboard for 3.5' and one for 4.0']

When I build and test my app using the 3.5 / 4 inch simulators and using my iPhone 4, the view layouts revert to how how they did prior to viewing as 6.1 or earlier, i.e. shifted up with white space at the bottom. Is this an IOS7 or XCode 5 feature does anyone know and what can I do to address this ? Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using a single storyboard for all sizes?

Comment: I know there are different ways of handling 3.5 and 4' screens, I just found this way simple to handle.

Comment: I have resolved my own issue by unchecking the Extend Edges - Under Top Bars